# Iterating over the objects in a folder on amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, guzzle

We have an application where in user can create his own webpages and host them.We are using S3 to store the pages as they are static.Here,as we have a limitation of 100 buckets per user,we decided to go with folders for each user inside a bucket.

Now,if a user wants to host his website on his domain,we ask him for the domain name(*when he starts we publish it on our subdomain*) and I have to rename the folder.

S3 being a flat file system I know there are actually no folders but just delimeter `/` separated values so I cannot go into the folder and check how many pages it contains.The API allows it one by one but for that we have to know the object names in the bucket.

I went through the docs and came across [iterators](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/feature-iterators.html),which I have not implemented yet.This uses [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) of which I have no experience and facing challenges in implementing

Is there any other path I can take or I need to go this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create an iterator for the contents of a "folder" by doing the following:

```
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket'    => 'bucket-name',
    'Prefix'    => 'subfolder-name/',
    'Delimiter' => '/',
));

foreach ($objects as $object) {
    // Do things with each object
}
```

If you just need a count, you could this:

```
echo iterator_count($s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket'    => 'bucket-name',
    'Prefix'    => 'subfolder-name/',
    'Delimiter' => '/',
)));
```

Comment: PLEASE SUGGEST.I am using [this](https://github.com/sachintaware/amazon-s3-php-class) minified version of the API as I don't require rest of the pacakages and I don't want to have unnecessary code for obvious reasons.This API has a `S3.php` file and it does not include the iterator functions,like `getListObjectsIterator`,so how can I merge the above code to the existing class as if I check the official code it involves namespaces and dependencies due to which entire package has to be included.Also,it uses guzzle and I have to install it on my server only for this,but I don't use it in my app.

Comment: The tpyo S3 class you are using is not supported by AWS and does *not* have the iterator features. The code I suggested above works only with the official [AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php). Using the official SDK is not difficult; you can install it via Composer or PEAR, or simply download and include the aws.phar. The user guide is located [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/index.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.I will definitely go ahead and work on the AWS official SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a learning curve with s3, eh? I spent about 2 hours and ended up with this codeigniter solution. I wrote a controller to loop over my known sub-folders.

```
function s3GetObjects($bucket) {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('aws_s3');

    $prefix = $bucket.'/';

    $objects = $CI->aws_s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
        'Bucket'    => $CI->config->item('s3_bucket'),
        'Prefix'    => $prefix,
        'Delimiter' => '/',
    ));

    foreach ($objects as $object) {

        if ($object['Key'] == $prefix) continue;

        echo $object['Key'].PHP_EOL;

        if (!file_exists(FCPATH.$object['Key'])) {

            try {
                $r = $CI->aws_s3->getObject(array(
                    'Bucket' => $CI->config->item('s3_bucket'),
                    'Key'    => $object['Key'],
                    'SaveAs' => FCPATH.$object['Key']
                ));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
                //return FALSE;
            }

            echo PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo ' -- file exists'.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```