# Using namespaces in PHP

Tags: php, class, namespaces, guzzle

I am working on the AWS documentation which uses Guzzle framework. I have to deal with namespaces here and I am not able to get it working. I went through the docs and examples and understood that we can have packages for projects using namespaces.

I went ahead and tried a simple example, but unsuccessful. Here's the example: this is the `index.php`:

```
     use My\Full\Classname as Another;  //Also tried use My\Full\Classname
     $obj = new Another;                //with  $obj = new Classname;    
     echo $obj->add();
```

I have `Classname.php` in the directory structure like this `My->Full->Classname.php`:

```
     <?php
        class Classname{
        public static function add(){
                return 2+2;
            }
         }
     ?>
```

I am trying to call the function in `index.php` but getting error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Another' not found in C:\wamp\www\guzzleEx\index.php on line 19
```

which is the line where I instantiate the Classname object  `$obj = new Another;`

What is the mistake i am making? Is there any `INI` that needs to be updated or any other config issue? How can I make the code working? If you use the normal `include` for Classname.php it works fine.

Comment: You still need to include (or autoload) the class file. All `use` does is alias a namespaced class name to a bare class name.

Comment: show the registered autoloader, and include `namespace My\Full;` as a first line in the `Classname` defining file

Comment: What is the registered autoloader? i just followed example over [here](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: You know that you have to include the class code in every place you want to use that class? Either manually by `include "path/File_With_Class.php"`, or with an autoloading function that does the include automatically.

Comment: Ok I was mistaken that namespaces automatically loads the class,bcoz the example I went through in the docs don't have any include statement(Guess they assume class is autoloaded),but that confused me.I am trying to integrate the guzzle framework in AWS api with my application,where I face the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces need to be explicitly declared, they do not come from a certain directory structure.

So if you do not have a line that reads `namespace My\Full;` in front of your `class Classname`, then your class is not in any namespace, but in the root namespace.

Thus you cannot use it as `\My\Full\Classname`, but `\Classname` or even `Classname` directly.

Comment: I tried this `namespace My\Full;
use My\Full\Classname;
$obj = new Classname;
echo $obj->add();` but still the same error! :P Do I need to change the dir structure also, i.e have the `classname` file at the same level to `index`

Comment: If you don't include the class, it cannot be found anywhere.

Comment: Ok,my actual issue is I am trying to use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) which powers AWS api and I want to use it for [iterators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893343/iterating-over-the-objects-in-a-folder-on-amazon-s3)(This was my question for it).So here theres no include statement in the files.So,are they using auto load?I downloaded it from GITHUB,but I am getting the same errors for all iterator classes.Please suggest the correct way.I need the right direction.